# Token browser dialog doesn't work

Tags: javascript, tokens

My Bootstrap based theme doesnot open the Token browser dialog.
This is a custom node form, and I want to put a browse Tokens Link like this

```
$form['field_']['token_tree'] = array('#theme' => 'token_tree_link');
```

Any workarounds?

I tried it in my form_alter with

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
```

I'we added jquery ui css/js dependencies but with no luck.

Comment: How exactly it breaks? What is the error message?

Comment: Its now as such resolved with the code                              
 $form['options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'use-ajax'; As i think ajax was not properly loading